# cajero automatico

Tags: c

estuve practicando este codigo sobre simular un cajero automatico, con un total de 100.000 pesos como saldo inicial, pero hay algo que me olvide y es que a medida que vaya ingresando la contraseña siendo 4 digitos por ejemplo "1234" cuando no pongo dicha contraseña, no deja de repetirse el "intente nuevamente" cuando la idea es que intente repetirse solo 3 veces, y que me salga un mensaje que diga "error: ingreso la contraseña 3 veces" este es el codigo que hice mas o menos

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int opc;
    int ndigitos = 4;
    int cuenta = 100000;
    int pin;
    int cantidad;
  
    printf("Ingrese su PIN de %d dígitos (1234): ", ndigitos);
    scanf("%d", &pin);
    
    while (pin != 1234) {
        printf("Intente nuevamente: ");
        scanf("%d", &pin);
    }
    printf("1) Extraer dinero\n");
    printf("2) Depositar dinero\n");
    printf("3) Consultar equilibrio\n");
    printf("4) Salir\n");
    
    printf("digite su opcion a realizar: ");
    scanf("%i",&opc);
    
    switch (pin) {
        case 1:
        
        printf("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero que desea extraer: ");
        scanf("%d", &cantidad);
            cuenta = cuenta - cantidad;
        printf("Excelente ha extraído %d", cantidad);
        break;
        
        case 2:
        printf("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero que desea depositar: ");
        scanf("%d", &cantidad);
            cuenta = cuenta + cantidad;
        printf("Excelente ha depositado %d", cantidad);
        break;
        
        case 3:
        printf("Cuentas con un saldo de %d", cuenta);
        break;
        
        case 4:
        printf("Salir del programa");
        
        default:
            printf("gracias y que tenga buen dia");
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

lo unico que quiero saber es como era para agregar el tema de la contraseña, que solo me deje ingresarla 3 veces, y que de esas 3 veces me salga su mensaje de error, nada mas, porfavor.

Answer (score 1):

Falta agregar una variable para contar el número de intentos.

Podría ser algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int opc;
    int ndigitos = 4;
    int cuenta = 100000;
    int pin;
    int cantidad;
    int intentos = 1;
  
    printf("Ingrese su PIN de %d dígitos (1234): ", ndigitos);
    scanf("%d", &pin);
    
    while (pin != 1234 && intentos < 3) {
        printf("Intente nuevamente: ");
        scanf("%d", &pin);
        intentos++;
    }
    
    if (intentos == 3){
        printf("error: ingreso la contraseña incorrectamente 3 veces");
        return 0;
    }
    
    printf("1) Extraer dinero\n");
    printf("2) Depositar dinero\n");
    printf("3) Consultar equilibrio\n");
    printf("4) Salir\n");
    
    printf("digite su opcion a realizar: ");
    scanf("%i",&opc);
    
    switch (pin) {
        case 1:
        
        printf("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero que desea extraer: ");
        scanf("%d", &cantidad);
            cuenta = cuenta - cantidad;
        printf("Excelente ha extraído %d", cantidad);
        break;
        
        case 2:
        printf("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero que desea depositar: ");
        scanf("%d", &cantidad);
            cuenta = cuenta + cantidad;
        printf("Excelente ha depositado %d", cantidad);
        break;
        
        case 3:
        printf("Cuentas con un saldo de %d", cuenta);
        break;
        
        case 4:
        printf("Salir del programa");
        
        default:
            printf("gracias y que tenga buen dia");
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```